# UIcollectionView Spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have 10 cells out of which the width of the 6th cell has to be different from others.I tried to change it in the flow delegate method. but something is going wrong with the spacing from 7th to 10th cell.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let widthOfCollectionView  = collectionView.bounds.width - 40;

 // For collectionView use "item" instead of "row" 
    if indexPath.item == 6{
        return CGSizeMake(widthOfCollectionView,100)
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(widthOfCollectionView/3, 100)
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 10;
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10;
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the width of small items you should return `(collectionView.bounds.width - 30)/3`, 5 for left inset, 5 for right inset and 2*10 for spacing = 30.
For the width of large item you should return `collectionView.bounds.width - 10`, 5 for left and 5 for right inset = 10.

You can replace this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let widthOfCollectionView  = collectionView.bounds.width - 40;
    if indexPath.item == 6{
        return CGSizeMake(widthOfCollectionView,100)
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(widthOfCollectionView/3, 100)
    }
}
```

With

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let smallItemWidth = floor((collectionView.bounds.width - 30)/3 * 1000) / 1000
    let largeItemWidth = collectionView.bounds.width - 10

    if indexPath.item == 6{
        return CGSizeMake(largeItemWidth, 100)
    }else{
        return CGSizeMake(smallItemWidth, 100)
    }
}
```

*Use floor() to round down large decimals

Comment: Can you please tell me why the same calculation is not working for edge inset 10 on all sides?   if indexPath.item == 6{
            return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.width - 20,height/4)
        }else{
            return CGSizeMake((collectionView.bounds.width - 40)/3, height/4)
        }

Comment: @ichanduu It's because when dividing if the decimals are too large the last decimal number is rounded up which makes the items bigger than they could fit in one row, see my edited answer for solution.

Comment: @ichanduu adjust the numbers according to your insets

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your code as follows:

```
 import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

        @IBOutlet weak var sampleCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

        let insetValue: CGFloat = 5.0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        // make a cell for each cell index path
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            // get a reference to our storyboard cell
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
            // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell

            return cell
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

            if indexPath.item == 6{
                return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.width - insetValue * 2,100)
            }else{
                return CGSizeMake(floor((collectionView.bounds.width - insetValue * 4)/3), 100)
            }
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {

            return insetValue;
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return insetValue;
        }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{

            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(insetValue, insetValue, insetValue, insetValue);
        }


    }
```

Final output:

[image]

To download the sample project, use the following link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/SampleCollectionView

Comment: Can you please tell me how it works for the UIEdgeInset 10 on all sides.I tried it and the same calculation is not working.

Comment: I will modify and back to you

Comment: Please check ... i edited my answer..Now you can change "insetValue" for any value you want..